# runElmProgram is not a function after adding a native js lib

Tags: elm

I am trying to use https://github.com/TheSeamau5/elm-storage/ with elm 0.18

when trying to run elm-reactor, I get this error:

- Uncaught TypeError: runElmProgram is not a function

but when I try to run: elm make src/Exercises.elm --warn --output elm.js

then I get no warnings but this errors:

- Uncaught ReferenceError: Elm is not defined
- Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'Native' of undefined

this is my elm-package:

```
{
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "summary": "helpful summary of your project, less than 80 characters",
    "repository": "https://github.com/user/project.git",
    "license": "BSD3",
    "source-directories": [".", "src"],
    "exposed-modules": [],
    "native-modules": true,
    "dependencies": {
        "elm-lang/core": "5.1.1 <= v < 6.0.0",
        "elm-lang/html": "2.0.0 <= v < 3.0.0",
        "elm-lang/dom": "1.1.1 <= v < 2.0.0",
        "NoRedInk/elm-simple-fuzzy": "1.0.2 <= v < 2.0.0"
    },
    "elm-version": "0.18.0 <= v < 0.19.0"
}
```

Comment: Try deleting the `elm-stuff` directory, then run `elm package install` and start up elm reactor again. It sounds like one of those odd cases where clearing things out may fix the problem.

Comment: I tried that, but no luck...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you were lucky this compiled as this is an old library. The Elm code itself looks seems to use syntax that has not changed since it was written, but the native code on which it relies has changed completely and that's what's causing your error.

You could try to use https://github.com/elm-lang/persistent-cache instead, but this is a package that seems to be deliberately left as is, and you are expected to use ports instead. Frustrating I know....

Comment: Thanks a lot. I ended up using ports as suggested.

Comment: Ops, sorry... Done now.
By the way, what would be the best practices for handling the return of ports?
Let's say I have 2 places I load data from localstorage. Should I have 2 separate ports or pass something like the function name to the port, and in the update do a case...of?
I am currently using the second option but not sure if that is a good idea